# How to update Cassandra Lucene index with a new column? rebuild or update index?

Tags: cassandra, lucene, cassandra-lucene-index

It seems that you can only create one Lucene index for one table in Cassandra.

And if you want to add a new field to the index, you need to drop that old Lucene index and reindex.

But reindex for data on one node is time consuming.

Am I right?

I didnt find a way to update the lucence index with a new column in Cassandra.

Appreciate your comment.

Thanks!